# Checking deployment status in 5 seconds

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I'm attempting to deploy a logic app from Visual Studio 2015, and getting this message for hours:

```
Checking deployment status in 5 seconds
Checking deployment status in 5 seconds
Checking deployment status in 5 seconds
Checking deployment status in 5 seconds
Checking deployment status in 5 seconds
```

**Are there basic gotchas or guidelines for deploying logic apps that we must know in order to avert this?**

This happens ONLY for this one specific logic app. All other logic apps in this resource group deploy without issue!

**What I've tried:**

1. deploying from multiple wifi networks
2. deleted the logic app from the portal and attempted to redeploy
3. opened VS as admin

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Is it deploying or not? How long it is taking to deploy?

Comment: please view my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that **one of the azure function apps that was a dependency for this logic app was not functioning.**

The deployment artifacts (the arm template and parameters), as well as going to the actual resource group yielded no help on tracking down the cause of the issue. The  *deployments* tab within the resource group, simply showed that the deployment was in-progress for hours.

It is only when I started to go through every action of the logic app, ensuring that all the dependencies and everything the logic app was referencing, was actually operational, that I finally discovered the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Any VS after 2015 with community edition or higher we should be able to deploy logic app from visual studio.

I would suggest you to do the following to troubleshoot:

1) Try deleting the logic app and rename it try to deploy it.

2) Try to look at the deployment tab in azure portal for the resource group which you logic app is tied with.E.g.

[image]

This will give the correct picture on the issue as you can see it in the screenshot.

3) Also please make sure you have right dependencies installed in your local machine

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio

Let me know if you want to discuss it further , we can explore the logs to check why it is stuck on the deployment.

Comment: thank you so much for this helpful answer, and your kindness in offering your help. please view my answer below

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Please accept it as an answer as it will help others who have the same ask.

Comment: will do! stackoverflow forces you to wait 24 hours before accepting your own answer, which is what i will do tomorrow